# Django - Auto populate created_by field outside django admin using form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

The users are asked to create a new instance outside the django admin by filling a form created by the modelformset_factory. The problem is that I dont know how to pass request.user to the form so the created_by field is not valid when the form is saved.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ezApp(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    in_use = models.BooleanField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from ezmapping.models import *
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

def setName(request):
    ezAppFormSet = modelformset_factory(ezApp, extra=1, fields=('name'))
    formset = ezAppFormSet(queryset=ezApp.objects.none())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ezAppFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
    return render_to_response("project/manage_new.html", {'formset': formset, 'title': "New"}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `created_by` field yourself before saving the instance.

Do something like this:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    for instance in instances:
        instance.created_by = request.user
        instance.save()
```

The documentation about this feature is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset).