# model no iterable "create by user" django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a problem,  when i try upload files I am trying show the user  uploaded the file but not working.

My model is this:

```
class Document(models.Model):
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 programa=models.CharField(max_length = 100)
 materia=models.CharField(max_length = 50)
 profesor=models.CharField(max_length = 50)
 usuario=models.ForeignKey(Usuario)
 add=models.DateTimeField ( auto_now = True )
 archivo= models.FileField(upload_to="archivos/",storage=OverwriteStorage(),null = False) 

 def __unicode__(self):
        return self.programa

 class Meta:
    db_table = u'utp_document'
```

My view is:

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def upload(request):

 if request.method=='POST':

     form=DocumentForm(request.POST,request.FILES,)
     if form.is_valid():
         instances = form.save(commit=False)
         for instance in instances:
            instance.usuario = request.user
            instance.save()



         return HttpResponseRedirect('/menu/')
 else:
     form=DocumentForm()

 return render_to_response('formulario_modal.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I followed this post [Django - Auto populate created_by field outside django admin using form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840615/django-auto-populate-created-by-field-outside-django-admin-using-form).

and this my form.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
    model = Document
    exclude = ('usuario',)
```

The problem is what i try new upload file get this error:

> 'Document' object is not iterable

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`form.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) returns a *single modal instance*:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.usuario.user = request.user
instance.save()
```

FYI, in the post you've linked a [*formset*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/) is used which is the reason for a loop.

Comment: but I get the error with which I have been trying to solve this is "Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: xxx>>": "Document.usuario" must be a "Usuario" instance."

Comment: @papo this is better and a different problem. Can you show how `Usuario` modal is defined? Thanks.

Comment: class UsuarioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ['nombres','correo']  equals the DocumentForm

Comment: @papo nono, I'm asking about the `Usuario` model.

Comment: ahhh is this class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    correo = models.EmailField()
    
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'utp_users'

Comment: @papo please check the update. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your patience but the error that appears is similar to the previous and this Document has no usuario is a bug the django 1.7.6??

Comment: the only solution I could find to this dilemma was to change the user variable in the model change Document usuario = models.ForeignKey  (User) for usuario = models.CharField ( max_length = 100 ) and apply the changes you suggested and it works. shame because I wanted to do with foreingkey but good intention that counts thanks :D