# Auto-populate Django template with context variable passed from a Django view (no js)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have Django template which has one `CharField`. Users can enter a mobile phone number here and submit it.

The view connected to this template sometimes passes to the said template, a context variable containing a pre-defined phone number `{{ number }}`.

How do I **auto-populate** the `CharField` in the Django template with `{{ number }}`?

The template code is like so:

```
<form action="{% url 'user_phonenumber' slug=unique num=decision %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<b style="font-size:90%;color:green;">Enter your mobile number:</b><br><br>
{{ form.mobile_number }}<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="number" value="OK"><br>
</form>
```

If required, **forms.py** contains the following:

```
class UserPhoneNumberForm(forms.Form):
    mobile_number = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        fields = ("mobile_number")
```

In **views.py**, I simply have:

```
class UserPhoneNumberView(FormView):
    form_class = UserPhoneNumberForm
    template_name = "get_user_phonenumber.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserPhoneNumberView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            #some code to determine what number should be
            context["number"] = number
        return context
```

I've looked at a few [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855816/auto-populating-created-by-field-with-django-admin-site) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840615/django-auto-populate-created-by-field-outside-django-admin-using-form) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values). The last one I've linked comes close to solving the problem, but the solution isn't for dynamic values (which is what I need), plus that's for modelforms. The rest don't quite address my particular needs.

Comment: You should show the view. Did you try passing the `initial` argument to the form instantiation, as shown in the docs under ["dynamic initial values"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)? And note that the last answer you link to shows you **exactly and precisely** what to do.

Comment: Added the view (it's a CBV). I didn't set `initial`. I'm now seeing what I'm doing wrong. Should I over-ride the `def get_initial(self):` method with the FormView CBV to achieve this?

Comment: [Initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#initial) is a keyword argument to a form field

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what `get_initial` is for in a FormView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to over-ride `def get_initial(self):` of my FormView to achieve this. I.e. instead of passing a context variable to the template, pass the variable as `initial` through `get_initial()` to the related form.

Here's how I did it:

```
def get_initial(self):
    """
    Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
    """
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        #What's the latest chatpicmessage which houses a pic you own
        try:
            msg = PicMessage.objects.filter(which_pic__owner=self.request.user).latest('sending_time')
            self.initial = {'mobile_number': msg.what_number} #initial needs to be passed a dictionary
            return self.initial
        except:
            return self.initial
    else:#i.e user is not authenticated
        return self.initial
    return self.initial
```

More documentation regarding this can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#initial